# R ggplot: I am having problem drawing R histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with the built-in esoph dataset. My task is to formulate a histogram of "ncontrols" variable for each age group in the dataset

Here are the codes I write down. First, I do the group_by on agegp (age groups,) calculate the total ncontrols (number of control cases) for each age group, and rename both agegp and ncontrols to something easily readable

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(datasets)  
library(ggplot2)

data_esoph <- esoph %>% group_by(agegp) %>% 
          summarise(Total_number_of_control_case = sum(ncontrols)) %>% 
          rename(Age_group = agegp)
```

Then I try to draw a histogram using geom_histogram

```
plot_histogram <- ggplot(data_esoph, aes(x = Age_group)) +
                  geom_histogram(color = 'black', fill = 'grey70') +    
       labs(title ="Number of control cases by age group",x = "Age group", y = "Cases")+
       theme(axis.title= element_text(size = 12), plot.title = element_text(size = 16))
```

I run into an error that says

> Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete.Perhaps you want stat="count"?

I know this error is because agegp (Age_group) is discrete variable. I try to convert it to numeric but to no avail. Anyone have any idea what can I do to fix this problem and draw a histogram ?

[image: data_esoph looks like this]

Comment: A histogram is the count of individuals per bin.  You all ready have that information, you need a bar or column graph.  Maybe this `ggplot(esoph, aes(x=agegp, y=ncontrols)) + geom_bar( stat="sum")`

Comment: The error essage actually suggests what to do.  See `?geom_histogram` about `stat="count"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `stat="identity"` to the `geom_bar` like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Age_group, y = Total_number_of_control_case)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(title ="Number of control cases by age group",x = "Age group", y = "Cases") +
  theme(axis.title= element_text(size = 12), plot.title = element_text(size = 16))
```

Output:

[image]

#### Data

```
df <- data.frame(Age_group = c("25-34", "35-44", "45-54", "55-64", "65-74", "75+"),
                 Total_number_of_control_case = c(115,190,167,166,106,31))
```

Comment: Thank you ! However, the task specifically requires me to draw a histogram and not a bar-chart. Is there anyway to draw a histogram ?

Comment: @AnhDuy, A histogram is for continuous data, so I would suggest using a barplot. What you can do is create the bars closer to each other.